# PHP MySQL - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have the following query working:

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT a.id FROM surf a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.user LEFT JOIN surfed c ON c.user = '".$data['id']."' AND c.site = a.id WHERE a.active = '0' AND (b.coins >= a.cpc AND a.cpc >= '2') AND (c.site IS NULL AND a.user !='".$data['id']."')".$dbt_value." ORDER BY a.cpc DESC LIMIT 1");
```

But I'd like to add the follow AND statements in to it:

```
 AND `cpc`<='10' AND (`id` NOT IN (SELECT `site` FROM `surfed_site`))
```

So i made it look like:

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT a.id FROM surf a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.user LEFT JOIN surfed c ON c.user = '".$data['id']."' AND c.site = a.id WHERE a.active = '0' AND (b.coins >= a.cpc AND a.cpc >= '2') AND `cpc`<='10' AND (`id` NOT IN (SELECT `site` FROM `surfed_site`)) AND (c.site IS NULL AND a.user !='".$data['id']."')".$dbt_value." ORDER BY a.cpc DESC LIMIT 1");
```

But then I receive this message:

Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

```
AND `cpc`<='10' AND (`id` NOT IN (SELECT `site` FROM `surfed_site`))
```

to

```
AND `cpc`<='10' AND (`a.id` NOT IN (SELECT `site` FROM `surfed_site`))
```

You need `a.id` because it's not sure which `id` column in which table to reference.

Comment: I then receive this: SQL Error: Unknown column 'a.id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery':

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that error is because there are multiple tables containing column `ID`. In order to execute the query, you must supply the table where the column `ID` resides in order for the server to identify which table is pertaining to, eg

```
AND `cpc`<='10' AND (a.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `site` FROM `surfed_site`))
```

if you mean that the `ID` you are comparing is from table `surf`

Comment: No the ID is from the table `surfed_site` what would I need to do to make it from `surfed_site`?

Comment: let me ask this first, what tables aside from `surfed_site` in your current query that contains column `ID`? second, what do you want to do with the `ID` on table `surfed_site`?

Comment: All of them have an ID in.  I want to check that the ID of the row pulled out of the `surf` table is not the in `surfed_site` table.

Comment: if that's the case, what happen if you will execute the query with `AND cpc<='10' AND (a.id NOT IN (SELECT site FROM surfed_site))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify which `id` you want. `a.id`, `b.id` etc.

Comment: Which letter should I use to check the `id` column from `surfed_site`?

Comment: @Liam Gordon 
Try `AND \`cpc\`<='10' AND (\`a\`.\`id\` NOT IN (SELECT \`site\` FROM \`surfed_site\`))`.

Answer (score 0):

Also I'm assuming $data contains escaped data (single quotes)?  If not that is a second issue.

Comment: The current query works perfectly until I add in them extra AND comments

Comment: I mean if “ isn't escaped, then there is also a MySQL injection security hole.

Comment: How would I go about checking?

Comment: Is id pulled in from a query param? Try passing " or ' in an id or form values.